# JDBC driver that can write to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

We tried using the Simba Driver for BigQuery on Pentaho Data Integration tool but encountered an error that streaming is not allowed while trying to update a BigQuery table. Can someone please confirm if this driver can be used to write into BigQuery or just read from it?
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/providers/simba-drivers

Also tried the CData driver which produces a similar error.

Are there other JDBC drivers that we could try?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You are talking about update during streaming? Are you updating data in streaming? updating schema?

Comment: Just trying to move some data from a PostgreSQL DB to BigQuery using Pentaho data integration tool. No schema update, a simple insert operation. Not sure what Pentaho does behind the scenes though.

Comment: The driver  used is the correct one,  please provide more context of the error message,  also confirm if you are following the  official PENTAHO [documentation](https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/9.1/Setup/Google_BigQuery) to perform this actions.